# Printing the total amount of time elapsed while processing the program

Tags: c++, timezone

I am trying a write a stopwatch which is used to keep track of the program's running time. The code showing the private members is as follows:-

```
#include <sys/time.h>

class stopwatch
{
 private:
  struct timeval *startTime;
  int elaspedTime;
  timezone *Tzp;

  public:   
  //some code here 
};
```

The problem is that while compiling the program, I am getting an error that `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'timezone' with no type`. I am thinking this might be due to library that I am using but I am not able to correct my mistake. I have searched on the internet but the only post about `<sys/time.h>` is that it is very obsolete now. They did not suggest any alternatives. Can you please me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `chrono`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto beg = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Do stuff here

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - beg).count() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/)

```
#include <iostream>     /* cout */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, difftime, time, mktime */

int main ()
{
  time_t timer;
  struct tm y2k;
  double seconds;

  y2k.tm_hour = 0;   y2k.tm_min = 0; y2k.tm_sec = 0;
  y2k.tm_year = 100; y2k.tm_mon = 0; y2k.tm_mday = 1;

  time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

  seconds = difftime(timer,mktime(&y2k));

  std::cout << seconds << "seconds since January 1, 2000 in the current timezone" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You can modify names as you want. Also, [here](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/03/14/create-a-timer/)'s a timer with `<sys/time.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on a windows environment, you can call `unsigned int startTime = timeGetTime()`[(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) once when the program starts and `unsigned int endTime = timeGetTime()` when it ends.  Subtract `endTime` from `startTime` and you have the number of milliseconds that have passed since the program started.  If you're looking for more accuracy, check out the [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.